# import a java class from a java file which contains multiple classes

Tags: java, exception

i am going through a situation where i have created multiple classes for custom exception in a single java file. as follow

```
    public class IllegalArgumentException extends Throwable {
        public IllegalArgumentException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }

    class InvalidDirectoryException extends Throwable {
        public InvalidDirectoryException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }

    class InvalidJsonFormatException extends Throwable {
        public InvalidJsonFormatException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }

    class InvalidFileTypeException extends Throwable {
        public InvalidFileTypeException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }
```

when I try to import one of the class then it is not resolving. I am only able to import IllegalArgumentException class. I dont want to make multiple java file for each class. So is there way to do it?

Comment: you have three options: make all of them inner classes of something like "CustomExceptions" (bad practice), have them be in different files (usually the best practice) or put your classes that are accessing them in the same package (cause the last 3 are package-private)

Comment: The InvalidDirectoryException , InvalidJsonFormatException ,InvalidFileTypeException  are package protected classes, are you trying to import them within the same package or? 

You are allowed to have only 1 public class per Java file, if you want to have 4 public classes , you have to create 4 different java files

Comment: Why would keeping everything in one file be preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont want to make multiple java file for each class.

You have to if you want to access them from other packages. In Java, every file must have exactly one public class. That is a rule. There could be valid reasons why you don't want a separate file for each class, but Java doesn't care about that.

You could try making each of them static inner classes in a single outer class, and then using `import static`, but that is a bad practice, as you would be abusing the intended purpose of inner classes, so I don't encourage using that method. But you could.

Comment: i don't want separate files. because if i need 100 of custom exception then why I would create 100 class.

Comment: @AashishVerma why not? What's bad about 100 files for 100 classes? That is, if you really need that many custom exceptions. It's possible you are designing your exceptions too fine-grained.

Answer (score 0):

Create one general public class and put all other classes as inner classes inside the main public class.

Example:

```
public class AllExeptions{

   class IllegalArgumentException extends Throwable {
        public IllegalArgumentException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }

    class InvalidDirectoryException extends Throwable {
        public InvalidDirectoryException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }

    class InvalidJsonFormatException extends Throwable {
        public InvalidJsonFormatException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }

    class InvalidFileTypeException extends Throwable {
        public InvalidFileTypeException(String exceptionString) {
            super(exceptionString);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not familiar with the Java inner class, then I recommend you this nince inner class tutorial by TutorialsPoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_innerclasses.htm